# update given data in binary file through python

Tags: python-2.7

I have created a binary file which contains

```
 roll numbers, name, father's name and mother's name.
```

I want to create a **python program** that can update these details by update I mean that the user would be able to change any of the given data through the python program.

this is the location of my binary file

```
 file2=open(r"C:\Users\pc\Desktop\itika study material\cs\student\data.log","rb")
```

Comment: How will the user change the data? Will they type it in? Will there be buttons?

Comment: they will type it during the runtime and this will lead to change in data in the binary file which has already been created

Comment: Start with some input statements and then add `with open()`

Comment: what exactly must be my approach for updating

Comment: The approach is to use `with open()`.

Comment: Yes. `with open(..,'wb+')`

Comment: You must use the with statement or your code will be buggy.